# asmx service returns xml instead of json

Tags: c#, json, ajax, xml, asmx

I am trying to set up a asmx service to return json inside the web method. When I view the response inside 
a browser instead of returning json I get xml. I have set up my web method to return the json format. 
Please find my web service below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace space_port_lander_real_app
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]


    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(CacheDuration = 60)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {

            //string xmlstring = "<user><name>Hello World</name><password>some pass</password></user>";

            //var name = $(xml).find('name').text();

            //return xmlstring;

            return "hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

The response output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">hello world</string>
```

I set up my method to return a string. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Side Note: Why an asmx service? Why not use web api instead?

Comment: What happens if you change your method to return an object? Example: `public object HelloWorld() { return new {Message = "hellow world"}; }`

Comment: What is the `content-type` header of your request? If I remember correctly ASMX services always return XML if the header does not specify otherwise...

Comment: You can only get what the server is designed to return.  Some server will return xml, some json, and some both.  when it supports both you may need to add a parameter to the request to specify the return format.

Comment: If inheriting from System.Web.Services.WebService you are creating a soap service, or these days I guess called a Xml web service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a GET method to return JSON, you need to set it otherwise use POST.

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Check [Here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks)